# Публикация двух версий приложения (Android)

Tags: android, google-play

Можно ли опубликовать Android приложение в Google консоли для двух разных версий? у меня не работает приложение на Android версий 4 и ниже, как лучше сделать?

Comment: Почему бы просто minSDK версию не понизить?

Comment: В файле AndroidManifest.xml. Ну или в градл скрипте, если он используется.

Comment: сейчас у меня 21 стоит, если поставлю на 16, норм будет?

Comment: Будет ли оно устанавливаться на старых версиях? Да. Будет ли оно работать? Не факт, особенно если вы используете вещи из SDK из более новых версий и не используете support library.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Собираете 2 (на самом то деле хоть сколько) разных APK для разных API level и выкладываете. Консоль Google Play это поддерживает.

Можно автоматизировать их сборку в Gradle - это называется `productFlavors`:

```
productFlavors {
        honeycumb {
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }
        kitkat {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }
    }
```

[Документация здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Comment: а можно ли на flavors сделать две сборки, в одной из которых отключить платные фичи? и как на это посмотрит google play при валидации, не будет ли отклонять из-за похожести?

Comment: Можно при условии, что у разных сборок будут разные `applicationId`